# How to expand only one item in a flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm a beginner in react-native and I'm using Flatlist to render a fruit list, the list is being rendered correctly, the problem is when I click to expand an item from the list, all other items expand as well. I made a gif that shows the current behavior and also put the code inside the snack to facilitate understanding.

[image: Current behavior]

[Code on Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@vbernal/flatlist-layoutanimation)

Can you tell me how to open just the item I click?

And also how do I make the first item of my Flatlist always come expanded by default?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your boolean value `true` is `true` for all list items, so that won't work. Obviously your `expanded` must be a *unique value*, that would be `fruit_name` (**NOT INDEX!**) and later compare that value.

```
onChangeLayout = (fruitName) => {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
    this.setState({ expanded: fruitName });
    this.componentDidMount();
  };

...

onPress={() => this.onChangeLayout(item.fruit_name)}

...

height: (this.state.expanded === item.fruit_name) ? null : 0,
```

On your request to expand first item as initial, you should do this in your fetch success scope block like this

```
.then(responseJson => {
  const dataSource = responseJson['data'];
  this.setState({
    fruitLIst: true,
    dataSource,
    expanded: (dataSource && !!dataSource.length) ? dataSource[0].fruit_name : null
 })
```

Also it's good practice having `componentDidMount` logic in another method that just gets called in this lifecycle.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much Jank!!! Only more thing, can you tell me how do I make the first item of my Flatlist always come expanded by default?

Comment: Hii @jank, this worked, now the first item appears expanded, however, the other items do not expand when I click, I updated the code in the snack if you want to see: https://snack.expo.io/@vbernal/flatlist-layoutanimation

Comment: @vbernal remove `this.componentDidMount();` in `onChangeLayout` method. You should never call `this.componentDidMount` in other methods because it's a lifecycle method

Comment: I'm going to get some other method to do, because when I remove componentDidMount() from onChangeLayout() the Layout Animation stops working, and no item is expanded again, I refreshed the code in the snack case in case you can see: https://snack.expo.io/@vbernal/flatlist-layoutanimation